# Append a file in Python 3 I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm able to open and write some headers to a csv file at the start of my code:

```
## Create the output file
with open(output_file, mode='w+') as csv_file:
                    fieldnames = ['Name', 'Instance ID', 'Type', 'State', 'Private IP', 'Public IP', 'Region', 'Availability Zone', 'Launch Time' ]
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    writer.writeheader()
```

But in the same program I build a list of EC2 instances, and try to print that list to the same file later on in the code, and I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\tdunphy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The is the code where I try to append to the file, that produces the above error:

```
with open(output_file, mode='a+') as csv_file:
    writer.writerow({'Name': name, 'Instance ID': instance_id, 'Type': instance_type, 'State': instance_state, 'Private IP': private_ips, 'Public IP': public_ips, 'Region': aws_region, 'Availability Zone': availability_zone, 'Launch Time': launch_time_friendly})
```

Why can't I write to this file? What can I do to correct that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to add back this line before trying to writerow, as the old writer may still be referring to a "closed" file in memory:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(path, 'w+') as f1:
     s = store(f1)
with open(path, 'a+') as f2:
     s.operate_on()
```

if the same as

```
try:
    f1 = open(path, 'w+') as f:
    s = store(f1)
finally:
    f1.close()
try:
    f2 = open(path, 'a+')
    s.operate_on()
finally:
    f2.close()
```

Perhaps this is more obvious what you're problem is. You're storing an open file object, then closing it, then opening some other file object `f2` which you never use and trying to operate on the closed file.

Your solution is to either put `writer.writerow(...)` in the first `with` block or just do

```
csv_file = open(output_file, mode='w+')
```

and be careful to close it later.

Alternatively, create a new `csv.DictWriter` with the new file object.